# How to upload Images to a Webserver with React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, react-native

So I am using React Native and trying to build a kind of socialmedia.

You have to give a name, age, and so on. Now I also want to add a feature, where the user can pick a profileimage. To get name, age, and so on to the Server I use a simple HTTP POST request, but how can I upload images to my webserver from React Native/Javascript. I also use Django as the backend, but that shouldn't be that relevant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

There are a lot of videos on the web. You simply have to look. I think this looks very good: **[Upload Images To A Webserver With React Native](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=how+to+upload+images+with+react+native&view=detail&mid=26428E4B093CD6C69E4526428E4B093CD6C69E45&FORM=VIRE)**

#### Solution 2

There is also a Website called react native schools. They have very good tutorials with the topic React Native: **[Upload Images To A Webserver With React Native](https://www.reactnativeschool.com/how-to-upload-images-in-a-react-native-app)**